# Kinetics of A + 2 B -> C reaction

Tags: kinetics, solutions

> A reaction $\ce{A + 2 B -> C}$ is carried out in constant volume at $\pu{227 ^\circ C}$. the volume is $\pu{2 L}$. There is no $\ce{C}$ at the beginning. $[\ce{A}]_0 = \pu{0.035 mol L-1}$. $\ce{B}$ concentration changes over time.
>
> \begin{array}{l|cccccccc}
> t~(\pu{min})& 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
> \hline
> [\ce{B}]~(\pu{mol L-1}) & 0.09 & 0.066 & 0.05 & 0.039 & 0.033 & 0.028 & 0.024& 0.023
> \end{array}
>
> **a**) At $t = 5$, what is the conversion rate?
>   **b**) Calculate the reaction rate of $\ce{C}$ by using graph method according to $\ce{C}$ at time $0$ and $6$.
>   **c**) Calculate the total pressure at time $3$.
>   **d**) If this reaction should have done at constant pressure what would be the volume change rate?

I answered the **a**, **c** and **d** questions, but I am not sure about it. I can not solve question **b**, graph method, these were my exam questions and I want to know correct answers. Here are my answers:

---

Part **a**.

$$t = \pu{5 min}$$
$$\ce{\underset{0.035}{A (g)} + 2 \underset{0.09}{B (g)} -> C (g)}$$

$\ce{A}$ is a limiting reactant. At constant volume

\begin{align}
[\ce{A}] &= [\ce{A}]_0 (1 - x) \\
[\ce{B}] &= [\ce{B}]_0 - 2x[\ce{A}]_0
\end{align}

$$\pu{0.028 mol L-1} = \pu{0.09 mol L-1} - 2 \cdot \pu{0.035 mol L-1} \cdot x \to x = 0.886$$

---

Part **b**.

$$-\ln{(1 - x)} = kt$$
$$t = 6$$
$$0.024 = 0.09 - 2 \cdot 0.035 \cdot x \to x = 0.943$$
$$-\ln{(1 - 0.943)} = 6k \qquad \color{red}{?}$$

---

Part **c**.

$$p_T = C_T RT$$
$$0.039 = 0.09 - 2 \cdot 0.035 \cdot x \to x = 0.728$$
\begin{align}
[\ce{A}] &= 0.035 (1 - 0.728) = 9.52 \cdot 10^{-3} \\
[\ce{B}] &= 0.039 \\
[\ce{C}] &= [\ce{A}]_0 \cdot x = 0.035 \cdot 0.728
\end{align}
$$C_T = 0.074$$
$$p_T = \pu{0.076 mol L-1} \cdot \pu{0.082 L atm mol-1 K-1} \cdot \pu{(273 + 227) K} = \pu{3.034 atm}$$

---

Part **d**.

$$\epsilon = \frac{1 - 3}{3} = -\frac{2}{3}$$
$$V = V_0(1 + \epsilon x) \qquad \color{red}{?}$$

Comment: I edited your question using MathJax and Markdown according to the guidelines (more or less). Please feel free to check the correctness and improve further (see formatting tips [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here))

Comment: @andselisk I'm not sure if you putting a ton of effort into formatting everybody's questions is a flaw... (if you nominate yourself for the next Mod elections, whenever it is, you'll have my vote :D)